# package imported from pip installed one instead of local file?

Tags: python

I have the following files:

```
projx
    proj1
        __init__.py
        mod1.py
    tests
        test_mod1.py
```

The package `proj1` is already installed on my development machine using `pip install`. And `test_mod1.py` has the following import

```
from proj1.mod1 import ....
```

However, when running `python proj1\tests\test_mod1.py` in directory `projx`, it still import the package from the old package of `proj1.mod1` installed by `pip install` instead of the new one from `.\proj1\mod1.py`. Shouldn't python use the later one because the current directory is the first item in `sys.path`?

I created and active venv. However, it got the following error when executing the test file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\test_......py", line 4, in <module>
    from proj1.mod1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj1'
```

I tried to use relative path.

```
from ..proj1 import *
```

But It got error of:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple version of the same package! Using: `pip install packageName` will download the newest version, using: `pip install packageName==1.0.0` will let you choose older versions aswell.

To import the newest: `import packageName`.
To import a specified: `import packageName_1.0.0`

However I think you are right, `CWD` should always be priority.

I think if you were to try this: `from .. import proj1`, because parent directories will not be searched for packages.

To demonstrate:

```
me@myPc /parentDir % ls

childDir

me@myPc /parentDir % cat childDir/cwd.py

import os
print(os.getcwd())

me@myPc /parentDir % python3 childDir/cwd.py

/parentDir
```

Even though your CWD when telling python to execute the script was `projx`, the CWD of your script will be it's location: `tests`. So using `from .. import proj1` would tell your script to look for `proj1` in it's parent directory and import it.